# Converting python object to String, edit it and convert back to original kind of object

Tags: python, matplotlib, translate-animation

Good evening, I have python object of this type. Is here any way to convert it to String, edit, and convert back?

```
 <class 'matplotlib.transforms.CompositeGenericTransform'>
```

When I print it by print(variable) it looks like this:

```
CompositeGenericTransform(CompositeGenericTransform(CompositeGenericTransform(CompositeGenericTransform(CompositeGenericTransform(TransformWrapper(BlendedAffine2D(IdentityTransform(),IdentityTransform())), CompositeGenericTransform(BboxTransformFrom(TransformedBbox(Bbox('array([[ -19.5      ,  -10.7983871],\n       [ 221.5      ,  140.7983871]])'), TransformWrapper(BlendedAffine2D(IdentityTransform(),IdentityTransform())))), BboxTransformTo(TransformedBbox(Bbox('array([[ 0.125,  0.25 ],\n       [ 0.9  ,  0.9  ]])'), BboxTransformTo(TransformedBbox(Bbox('array([[ 0.,  0.],\n       [ 8.,  6.]])'), Affine2D(array([[ 80.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,  80.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   1.]])))))))), Affine2D(array([[ 0.99968918, -0.02493069,  6.98903935],
       [ 0.02493069,  0.99968918, -8.59039721],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ]]))), Affine2D(array([[ 0.99968918, -0.02493069,  6.93499095],
       [ 0.02493069,  0.99968918, -7.14592338],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ]]))), Affine2D(array([[ 0.99968918, -0.02493069,  6.88226449],
       [ 0.02493069,  0.99968918, -6.30113809],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ]]))), Affine2D(array([[ 0.99968918, -0.02493069,  6.96735103],
       [ 0.02493069,  0.99968918, -7.27368166],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ]])))
```

Comment: Why do you want to turn it into a string first?

Comment: I want edit numbers in penultimate array, and delete first "CompositeGenericTransform(" text, and I do not know the way how to do it, when it`s not a string ...

Comment: Describe what you actually want to do—not vaguely, but specifically—and someone can show you the way to do it. Converting to string and back is almost certainly _not_ the way to do it. See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Anyway, since the arguments to `CompositeGenericTransform` (which are the things it prints out as its `str`) are two transforms, deleting the first `CompositeGenericTransform(` would give you two separate transforms separated by commas followed by a `)`. What would you want that to mean?

Comment: I need to merge these CompositeGenericTransformations into one. I hope when I multiply matrixes elements among themselves it could be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with [Pickle](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle), it is an object serialization library for Python.

Answer (score 2):

You can use pickle with dumps and loads, but it may be fragile. Not advised.

```
import pickle

x  = {'a':1,'b':2}
out = pickle.dumps(x)
out = out.replace("I1","I66")
x2 = pickle.loads(out)
print x2 # {'a': 66, 'b': 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, this is not doable. Most objects cannot be constructed from their `str` representation.* (*Some* objects can be constructed from their `repr`, but you shouldn't rely on that.)

In specific cases, you can of course write a specific parser for whatever the type's `str` is.

But this is almost always a bad idea. Instead, choose an interchange format, then write code to convert your object to that interchange format and back. Many objects (especially in the NumPy family) *already* know how to render themselves as/construct themselves from various textual formats, like CSV or JSON, so it's just as matter of calling `astext` and `fromtext` or `tojson` and `fromjson` or whatever.

---

* Even strings can't be constructed from their `str` representation; it's really only numbers and the basic collections that can.